# Converting a dataframe into a long format contingency table for network analysis purposes

Tags: r, dataframe, count, data-conversion

This is probably very basic (sorry), but I'm a beginner in coding and haven't been able to find instructions online. I use R and have a dataframe like this:

```
id<-c(1:4)
happy<-c(1,0,1,0)
sad<-c(0,0,0,1)
angry<-c(0,1,0,0)
excited<-c(1,0,1,1)
emot<-data.frame(id, happy, sad, angry, excited)
emot
  id happy sad angry excited
  1     1   0     0       1
  2     0   0     1       0
  3     1   0     0       1
  4     0   1     0       1
```

id signifies a person and the other variables signify whether the person mentioned a certain emotion (1) or not (0). I'd like to convert the dataframe to obtain this result:

```
source target  count
happy  sad      0
happy  angry    0
happy  excited  2
sad    angry    0
sad    excited  1
angry  excited  0
```

I really tried with the table function, but to no avail. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R you could do something like:

```r
combo <- combn(names(emot)[-1], 2)

as.data.frame(t(combo)) |>
  setNames(c("target", "source")) |>
  transform(count = sapply(asplit(combo, 2), \(x) sum(rowMeans(emot[,x]) == 1L)))
```

Basically, get all the combinations of your column names, excluding `id`, and then iterate to retrieve those columns and apply some logic.

**Output**

```
  target  source count
1  happy     sad     0
2  happy   angry     0
3  happy excited     2
4    sad   angry     0
5    sad excited     1
6  angry excited     0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a <- crossprod(as.matrix(emot[-1]))
names(dimnames(a)) <- c('target', 'source')
as.data.frame.table(a, responseName = 'count')[c(upper.tri(a)),]

   target  source count
5   happy     sad     0
9   happy   angry     0
10    sad   angry     0
13  happy excited     2
14    sad excited     1
15  angry excited     0
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I tried crossprod too but incorrectly. And, I didn't realize - is my original dataframe already an adjacency matrix? I thought I would need to convert it into some type of matrix with emotions as both columns and rows, so I figured I'd try to get a "from-to" data frame that I'm more familiar with.

Comment: `c(upper.tri(a))` works the same as `upper.tri(a)`

Comment: @Sointu you are right. You do not have an adjacency matrix. tin the above code `a` is the adjacency matrix.

Comment: @LMc in this case yes, but not always. eg try `tibble(as.data.frame.table(a))[upper.tri(a),]` versus `tibble(as.data.frame.table(a))[c(upper.tri(a)),]` and see what happens.